# How to validate if the data is entered in the text field when the checkkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form where I need to validate that - "If the user checks the checkbox, they must enter data in the text field. I have the following JS where I can verify the parent/child checkbox validation, but I am not sure how to use the script for text field validation. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkBtn').click(function() {
      checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

      if(!checked) {
        alert("You must check at least one checkbox.");
        return false;
      }

    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="model"> Model #
<input type="text" size="12" class="childModel"><BR>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="checkBtn" style="text-align:center;"/>
```

Comment: *"I am not sure how to use the script for text field validation"*. Okay, so...did you look it up, attempt to learn, or try it yourself? There isn't any question here, and the implied "How do I do this?" without showing an attempt of your own is not a valid Stack Overflow question. (If you contend that your included code is your attempt, then I'd counter by saying that if you had written the code in your question, then you'd certainly know how to validate a textbox).

Comment: @Santi - I did try for a couple of hours, but was not getting anywhere.

Comment: Understood, but consider providing at least an attempt. We're here to tell you where you went wrong or why you're getting certain errors. If you've been at it for hours as you've said, then surely you can share the code you've tried that didn't work. Unfortunately, your "question" in its current form says *"Here's a code that validates checkboxes. Can someone write one for textboxes for me?"* and is too broad.

Comment: Apologize for that. Next time, I will make sure to take care of the notes from you. Thanks for your input!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got the answer, just keep it in mind for next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to check that:

- either the checkbox is unchecked, OR
- there's something in the checkbox

Here's a simple way to do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkBtn').click(function() {
      var isCheckboxChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
      var isTextEntered = $("input.childModel").val().length;
      
      if ( isTextEntered || !isCheckboxChecked ) {
          alert("validation passed!");
      } else {
          alert("validation failed!");
      }

    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="model"> Model #
<input type="text" size="12" class="childModel"><BR>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="checkBtn" style="text-align:center;"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the script. I voted up your answer initially, But, by mistake I voted down(HONEST MISTAKE). I am not able to vote up anymore. Sorry about that!